# Utorrent server downloads and uploads stuck at <1%

Tags: downloads, utorrent

I' using 18.04 and installed utorrent server using the following guide: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-utorrent-ubuntu-18-04-19-04

I managed to download 3 files and thought maybe I would make utorrent autorun at boot, so I followed the second step of said guide.
It worked (meaning utorrent now starts at boot), but I can't down or upload anything - it starts, then when reaches 1% it says "STOPPED" and goes back to 0%.

I'm guessing that it is something with utorrent not having write access to the download directory (I had set it to 'downloads' at first) but I can't find the folder mentioned in the guide 'home/username/utorrent' which supposedly utorrent has write access to, nor can I find the opt folder.
I could also give utorrent write access to my download folder -can anyone show me the commands?

Comment: Are you sure you need a server, and not just a client like Transmission?

Comment: I don't like utorrent's client.
If I can't find an answer I'll just go ahead and install the client.

Comment: The packages on the utorrent download site are all very old. It is no wonder they don't work on 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my post with an obvious answer: give utorrent write access to my 'downloads' folder.
Since I have seen this question many times before,so I just used chown:

sudo chown -R utorrent:utorrent /home/***/Downloads

Where *** is my username.